# adjust build.gradle for api 26 in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, gradle, build

when i run `flutter build apk --split-per-abi` it builds apk but it doesn't install on my phone(my phone cpu type is :armeabi-v7a and android 8.0 with api 26)

here is a part of my build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example...."
        minSdkVersion 20
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }
```

Comment: try to upgrade target sdk to 30 or 29

Comment: use this command: 'flutter run'

Comment: @Muhtar I did but my phone doesn't support that, it should be 26. and idk why it doesn't install however it is 26 and my phone is too.

Comment: @Benyamin i try to install apk on my actual phone not emulator

Comment: it will also work on real phones, no difference. before that you should enable developer options and enable USB debugging.